# create a table from a dataframe using RODBC

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am connecting to a SQL Server using ODBC and want to create a table from a dataframe. Following RODBC vignette below is my code,

```
library(RODBC) 
channel <- odbcConnect("DSN#", uid = "uname", pwd = "pwd")
ana.cars.df <- data.frame(mtcars)
sqlSave(channel, ana.cars.df)
```

And below is the error that I am getting

> Error in sqlSave(channel, ana.cars.df) :    42000 102 [FreeTDS][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'rownames'. [RODBC] ERROR: Could not
>   SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE ana.cars.df  ("rownames" varchar(255),
>   "mpg" float, "cyl" float, "disp" float, "hp" float, "drat" float, "wt"
>   float, "qsec" float, "vs" float, "am" float, "gear" float, "carb"
>   float)'

I have tried other options such as append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, etc but the nature of the error is same.

Comment: Is it trying to make a table named ana.cars.df? I bet you can't have "." in a table name. Just a guess.

Comment: Does `sqlSave(channel, mtcars)` work?

Comment: No it does not. Also in the table definitions "." is allowed in a name.

Comment: I tried creating the table first in DB and then updating it also,  sqlUpdate(channel, ana.cars,tablename="ana.cars", index=c("mpg")) similar error, [RODBC] Failed exec in Update42000 102 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'cycle'.

Comment: Came here from link on another question, SQL Server periods are qualifiers between [database.schema.table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx), not within table names.