# Errors using RODBC to Create/Populate ORACLE table

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

Similar symptoms as [create a table from a dataframe using RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440662/create-a-table-from-a-dataframe-using-rodbc).

**First Attempt**

I'm connecting to ORACLE successfully with `readOnly=FALSE`, and can retrieve data using `sqlQuery`.  I created a test table *RTest* with a single `NUMBER(16,8)` field called *Value*.  I can insert into the table from R using:

```
sqlQuery(channel,"insert into RTest (value) values(25)")
```

So I appear to have WRITE permissions.

**Next Attempt**

Following several internet examples, I created an R `data.frame` test with a single row and column and named *Value* where I attempted:

```
sqlSave(channel, test, "RTest", fast=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

and with `safer=TRUE`.  I receive an Oracle error:

> ORA-00922 - missing or invalid option. and RODBC error: "Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE DSN=...."

So, `sqlSave` appears to be attempting to create the table.  I've added and deleted options: `rownames=FALSE`, `colnames=FALSE`, `safer=TRUE/FALSE`, `varTypes=list`, and `varInfo=list` to no avail.

**Final Attempt**

Next I deleted the table in ORACLE and used `sqlSave` with `safer=TRUE` that should have created the table based on the `data.frame` structure but receive same error.

Eventually, I need to periodically read data files and process in R then upload 100+ fields with millions of rows.  Queries against an Oracle table will help with memory requirements to perform analyses and preclude reading the data into R from zipped files every time.

The help articles on inserting a `data.frame` into ORACLE via RODBC appear simple with default options. I thought this was a no-brainer, but this error keeps cropping up.  Any clues?

**New Information**
    **Some progress:**
1) Noted that connection uses case="nochange" and ORACLE defaults for tables and fields within tables is upper case.  sqlSave attempts used lower case.  Error changed when coordinated table name case.
2) Discovered through trial and error that ORACLE required a two part name USERNAME.TableName.
3) R numeric columns are double, oracle fields were defined NUMERIC(16,8) [and later (34,17)] which should hold the necessary digits.  R generated data type errors trying to convert binary double.  So switched Oracle to binary double and that error disappeared.

**Response to Information Requests and New Problem Description**
    See following session text.  Note that the local server name was replaced with {DummyServerName}, and the user name with {UserName}.

**  Create ORACLE table to match base R data frame USArrests**

```
## in Oracle create table to match data types in demo data.frame USArrests
SQL> CREATE TABLE "{UserName}"."RTEST"
2     ("Murder" BINARY_DOUBLE,
3     "Assault" DECIMAL,
4     "UrbanPop" DECIMAL,
5     "Rape" BINARY_DOUBLE,
6     "State" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
7     );

Table created.

SQL> desc RTEST
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
Murder                                             BINARY_DOUBLE
Assault                                            NUMBER(38)
UrbanPop                                           NUMBER(38)
Rape                                               BINARY_DOUBLE
State                                              VARCHAR2(255)
```

**   Connection Details**

```
 ## establish ORACLE connection in R
 library(RODBC)
 channel <- odbcConnect("{DummyServerName}", readOnly=FALSE, connection="TNS", case="nochange", believeNRows=FALSE)
 odbcGetInfo(channel)
DBMS_Name       DBMS_Ver   Driver_ODBC_Ver  Data_Source_Name   Driver_Name 
 "Oracle"   "11.02.0030"           "03.52"         "Default" "SQORA32.DLL" 
  Driver_Ver      ODBC_Ver         Server_Name
"11.02.0003" "03.80.0000" "{DummyServerName}"
```

The odbcGetInfo results indicate successful connection

**Insert manually into at table from R **

```
### manually insert value into table to show write capability
y <- sqlQuery(channel,"insert into {UserName}.RTEST values(25,26,27,28,'JUNK')")
y
character(0)
```

#### examine the table

```
x <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from RTest")
x
  Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape State
1     25      26       27   28  JUNK
```

So a manual insertion is successful.  I can insert from R, but so far not from sqlSave.

**Attempt to add value from data.frame using sqlSave**

```
##use data frame from R examples  
attach(USArrests)
The following objects are masked from USArrests (pos = 3):

Assault, Murder, Rape, UrbanPop

##capture the state names from the rownames to match ORACLE table structure
State<-rownames(USArrests)
Arrests2<-cbind(USArrests[,1:4],State)

typeof(Arrests2)
[1] "list"
class(Arrests2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

**Now attempt to populate the ORACLE table using sqlSave...**

```
sqlSave(channel,Arrests2,tablename="{UserName}.RTEST", fast=FALSE, safer=TRUE,rownames=FALSE)
Error in sqlSave(channel, Arrests2, tablename = "{UserName}.RTEST", fast = FALSE,  : 
table ‘{UserName}.RTEST’ already exists
```

** OK - safer=TRUE should have appended, but see if forcing an append will work using append=TRUE instead **

```
sqlSave(channel,Arrests2,tablename="{UserName}.RTEST", fast=FALSE, append=TRUE, rownames=FALSE)
Error in sqlSave(channel, Arrests2, tablename = "{UserName}.RTEST", fast = FALSE,  : 
unable to append to table ‘{UserName}.RTEST’
```

** now let R create the table **

```
##In ORACLE...
SQL> drop table RTEST;

Table dropped.
```

### back in R - safer=TRUE should create the table if it does not exist

### apply sqlSave using ?sqlSave defaults, omit rownames to match table structure

```
sqlSave(channel,Arrests2,tablename="{UserName}.RTEST", fast=FALSE, safer=TRUE,rownames=FALSE)
Error in sqlSave(channel, Arrests2, tablename = "{UserName}.RTEST", fast = FALSE,  : 
HY000 902 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00902: invalid datatype

[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE {UserName}.RTEST  
(DSN={DummyServerName}MurderDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}AssaultDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}UrbanPopDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}RapeDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double,
 DSN={DummyServerName}StateDSN={DummyServerName} varchar(255))'
```

** follow the sqlSave example exactly - this should create table USArrests **

```
sqlSave(channel, USArrests, rownames = "state", addPK=TRUE) 
Error in sqlSave(channel, USArrests, rownames = "state", addPK = TRUE) : 
HY000 922 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE DSN={DummyServerName}USArrestsDSN={DummyServerName}  
(DSN={DummyServerName}stateDSN={DummyServerName} varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}MurderDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}AssaultDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}UrbanPopDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}RapeDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double)'
```

**perhaps the uname qualifier is needed in tablename - force the table names **

```
sqlSave(channel, USArrests, tablename="{UserName}.USARRESTS", rownames = "state", addPK=TRUE)
Error in sqlSave(channel, USArrests, tablename = "{UserName}.USARRESTS",  : 
HY000 902 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00902: invalid datatype

[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE {UserName}.USARRESTS  
(DSN={DummyServerName}stateDSN={DummyServerName} varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}MurderDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}AssaultDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}UrbanPopDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}RapeDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double)'
```

**Finally, keep uname qualifier - force the table names, and use safer=TRUE that should create the table  **

```
sqlSave(channel, USArrests, tablename="{UserName}.USARRESTS", rownames = "state", addPK=TRUE, safer=TRUE)
Error in sqlSave(channel, USArrests, tablename = "{UserName}.USARRESTS",  : 
  HY000 902 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00902: invalid datatype

[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE {UserName}.USARRESTS  
(DSN={DummyServerName}stateDSN={DummyServerName} varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}MurderDSN={DummyServerName} binary_double, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}AssaultDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}UrbanPopDSN={DummyServerName} decimal, 
 DSN={DummyServerName}RapeDSN={DummyServerName}  binary_double)'
```

Still confused.  Closest success was with existing table and "safer=true" but the insert failed.  Examining the sqlSave code that generates the error message shows that error occurs when sqlwrite returns -1, which I assume is a failure.  Failure of sqlSave examples may indicate a local ORACLE

Comment: Are you really sure that is the error output? Why is *DSN* appearing with equality? Can you post entire error without omitting using `...`? And can you post connection assignment (anonymize any credentials).

Comment: I made some progress but errors still prevent loading an R data frame.  I added the connection info as requested and the errors from several attempts. See the edited question.

Comment: Very strange `CREATE TABLE` statements to have DSN info bleed through like that. Maybe your Oracle ODBC driver is not updated or is too new or [ROracle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) is not updated. And incompatibility creates this issue.

Comment: Possibly too the RODBC library which is a catch-all library for any ODBC-compliant database (SQLite, SQL Server, MySQL, MS Access) does not align to Oracle's dialect. Even ping authors on this interesting issue. Consider [ROracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/roracle/overview/index.html) specifically tailored to the RDBMS.